# Prompt no android lollipop com botão desalinhado

Tags: android, prompt

Estou com um problema em um prompt, no Android Kitkat (19) ou versão anterior fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém no lollipop ou versões mais novas fica desalinhado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código do listener que faz esse código:

```
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                Button noButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                Button yesButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

                noButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                yesButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    Drawable buttonDrawableNo = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_prompt, context.getTheme());
                    Drawable buttonDrawableYes = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_prompt, context.getTheme());

                    noButton.setBackground(buttonDrawableNo);
                    yesButton.setBackground(buttonDrawableYes);
                }
                else
                {
                    Drawable buttonDrawableNo = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_prompt);
                    Drawable buttonDrawableYes = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_prompt);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
                        noButton.setBackground(buttonDrawableNo);
                        yesButton.setBackground(buttonDrawableYes);
                    } else {
                        noButton.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonDrawableNo);
                        yesButton.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonDrawableYes);
                    }
                }
                noButton.invalidate();
                yesButton.invalidate();
            }
        });
```